# How can I find out if an SKTexture is the placeholder image

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

In SpriteKit, if you load an image with the [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:] method, it will first search your bundles, then atlases, if it fails to find your texture, it will then create a placeholder image and load it.

Is there a way to find out (without visually checking) if the loaded image is a placeholder?

This doesn't seem like a very "cocoa" way to handle this type of error.

developer.apple.com is down now, so I figured I would pose this question to SO.

Comment: Yes, use SpriteKit-QuickLook from github, then you can see private vars of the texture. There's an ivar that points to the original texture (atlas) if the texture is an atlas texture

Comment: Also, the MissingResource.png is 128x128 - you can compare the texture size if you don't use any textures of that size yourself.

Comment: Did you ever find a good way to do this?  I'm preloading textures and one in thirty launches I get Error Loading Image Resource for 3 or 4 textures.  I've been trying to find any way to find out with code if this happens and then reload them if it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SKTexture has some private properties that would be helpful (see e.g. https://github.com/luisobo/Xcode-RuntimeHeaders/blob/master/SpriteKit/SKTexture.h), but in Swift and during development I'm using this:

```
extension SKTexture {
    public var isPlaceholderTexture:Bool {
        if size() != CGSize(width: 128, height: 128) {
            return false
        }

        return String(describing: self).contains("'MissingResource.png'")
    }
}
```

**Attention!**:

This only works, if you are using a `SKTextureAtlas`:

```
let t1 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "MySprites").textureNamed("NonExistingFoo")
// t1.isPlaceholderTexture == true

let t2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "NonExistingBar")
// t2.isPlaceholderTexture == false
```

Comment: This question is a bit old, but I will accept this one.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the atlas contains the image. I created the following method in my AtlasHelper:

```
+(BOOL) isTextureWithName:(NSString *) name existsInAtlas:(NSString *)atlasName
{
    SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:atlasName];
    return [atlas.textureNames containsObject:name];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Swift version of the answer:

```
guard let spriteNode = node as? SKSpriteNode,
      let nodeName = spriteNode.name
else { return }
        
let nextAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(
    named: "2ndPlayer-Skin2")

if nextAtlas.textureNames.contains(
   "\(nodeName)-Skin2.png") { // NEED FULL NAME

     let texture = nextAtlas.textureNamed(
                "\(nodeName)-Skin2")  // DONT NEED FULL

     spriteNode.texture = texture   
     spriteNode.size = texture.size()
}
```

Thankfully this works, of course there's always some "way" right? ;)